# Chrome error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, typeerror

I wonder if anyone can help with a problem that I am having with getting this to work in Chrome.  Seems to be working in IE without any issues.....

I have the following HTML code which creates a table:

```
<table class="filter_table">
<tr>
<td class="filter_table">
Booking Number: <input type="textbox" id="filterbybookingnumber" name="filterbybookingnumber">
</td>
<td class="filter_table">
Cruise Code: <input type="textbox" id="filterbycruisecode" name="filterbycruisecode">
</td>
<td class="filter_table">
Tier Two Required: 
<select id="filterbytier2required" name="filterbytier2required">
<option value="">No Pereferance</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select> 
</td>
<td class="filter_table">
Cruise Op Required: 
<select id="filterbycruiseopsrequired" name="filterbycruiseopsrequired">
<option value="">No Pereferance</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select> 
</td>
<td class="filter_table">
<input type="button" value="Filter" id="filterbutton" onclick="FilterOne();">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr id="<%= row %>">
<td class="someClass"><input type="textbox" id="Col00R<%= row %>" value="<%= column00 %>" style="width:75px;" readonly class="textbox"></textbox></td>
<td class="someClass"><input type="textbox" id="Col0R<%= row %>" value="<%= column0 %>" style="width:75px;" readonly class="textbox"></textbox></td>
<td class="someClass"><input type="textbox" id="Col1R<%= row %>" value="<%= column1 %>" style="width:75px;" readonly class="textbox"></textbox></td>
<td class="someClass"><input type="textbox" id="Col2R<%= row %>" value="<%= column2 %>" style="width:75px;" readonly class="textbox"></textbox></td>
<td class="someClass"><input type="textbox" id="Col3R<%= row %>" value="<%= column3 %>" style="width:75px;" readonly class="textbox"></textbox></td>
<td class="someClass"><input type="button" id="<%=row%>" value="Select" style="width:75px;" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></td>
</tr>
<%
row = row + 1
Next
%> 
</table>
```

I then have a javascript function within the head of the document, which runs when the filter button is clicked.

```
<script>
function FilterOne()
{
var table = document.getElementById("entries");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var filterbybookingnumber = document.getElementById("filterbybookingnumber").value
var filterbycruisecode = document.getElementById("filterbycruisecode").value
var filterbytier2 = document.getElementById("filterbytier2required").value
var filterbycruiseops = document.getElementById("filterbycruiseopsrequired").value
var searchstring = ""
if (filterbybookingnumber !== "")
{
searchstring = searchstring + filterbybookingnumber
} else {
searchstring = searchstring + ""
}
if (filterbycruisecode !== "")
{
searchstring = searchstring + filterbycruisecode
} else {
searchstring = searchstring + ""
}
if (filterbytier2 !== "")
{
searchstring = searchstring + filterbytier2
} else {
searchstring = searchstring + ""
}
if (filterbycruiseops !== "")
{
searchstring = searchstring + filterbycruiseops
} else {
searchstring = searchstring + ""
}
//open the for loop
for(j = 1; j < rows.length; j++)
{
var filterbybn = document.getElementById("col1R" + j).value
var filterbycc = document.getElementById("col3R" + j).value
var filterbyt2 = document.getElementById("col15R" + j).value
var filterbyco = document.getElementById("col16R" + j).value
var searchresults = ""
if (filterbybookingnumber !== "")
{
searchresults = searchresults + filterbybn
} else {
searchresults = searchresults
}
if (filterbycruisecode !== "")
{
searchresults = searchresults + filterbycc
} else {
searchresults = searchresults
}
if (filterbytier2 !== "")
{
searchresults = searchresults + filterbyt2
} else {
searchresults = searchresults
}
if (filterbycruiseops !== "")
{
searchresults = searchresults + filterbyco
} else {
searchresults = searchresults
}
if ((searchstring) == (searchresults))
{
document.getElementById(j).style.display = "table-row";
} else {
document.getElementById(j).style.display = "none";
}
//close the for loop.
}
//close the function.
}
</script>
```

All is working in IE but its coming up with the following error in Chrome, it particular to:

```
var filterbybn = document.getElementById("col1R" + j).value
var filterbycc = document.getElementById("col3R" + j).value
var filterbyt2 = document.getElementById("col15R" + j).value
var filterbyco = document.getElementById("col16R" + j).value
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: You have to write capital C at the beginning with your ids at the first place: document.getElementById("C....").value

Comment: Thanks so much for that Blauharley, been looking at that for ages and never spotted it. :-D

Comment: You are welcome, have a nice weekend :)